# SQL: List unique substring from fields in table

Tags: mysql

I'm running a query to retrieve the first word from a string in a colum like so..

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( `field` , ' ', 1 ) AS `field_first_word`FROM `your_table`
```

But this allows duplicates, what do I need to add to the statement to get unique list of words out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX( `field` , ' ', 1 ) AS `field_first_word` FROM `your_table`
```

**Note:** There are performance implications for `DISTINCT`. However, in your case, there is likely limited pure MySQL alternatives.

Comment: No worries. Enjoy tomorrow. Just 10pm here.

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicates in a `SELECT` statement, change to `SELECT DISTINCT column`. In this case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX( `field` , ' ', 1 ) AS `field_first_word`FROM `your_table`
```